# Usage UIView vs. CAShapeLayer (drawing, animating, user interaction)

Tags: ios, uikit, core-animation

I have a pretty basic question: How do you choose between using `UIView` and `CAShapeLayer` when you want to draw shapes (I'm not talking about `textfields`, `switches` or other controls, just drawing)?

My understanding is that `UIView` (as part of `UIKit`) uses a normal `CALayer` under the hood to draw its content. If this is correct, then `CAShapeLayer` (or `CALayer` in general) would be the exact same thing, only without the extras `UIKit` gives you.

Then, when does using a `UIView` make sense, and when does using `CAShapeLayer` make sense?

Is `CAShapeLayer` faster? Is `UIKit` more optimised for gesture recognition or user interaction in general?

---

To give you more context, here's what I was trying to do when this question came up:

[image: Illustration]

I want these red circles to rotate around the center circle. However, the user should be able to tap on the red circles while they are rotating.

Here, I see two main options (there may be more) to add one of those red circles:

1. Create a `UIView`, manipulate its layer's cornerRadius and rotate it using `CGAffineTransform`.
2. Create a `CAShapeLayer` with a `UIBezierPath`. I could rotate it using `CATransform3D`

The only problem I have here is the `user interaction`. As it's constantly moving (rotating), I'd have to access the correct frame. I can do that using the `presentation layer` (which I think `UIView` is also using under the hood).

At this point, I'm not sure whether to use `UIView`s or `CAShapeLayer`s. Also, I'm not sure if animating it this way is the correct way in this case. There may be better options that will also erase the question about which one to use.

Thanks for your thoughts about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from Apple's doc

> Layers are not a replacement for your app’s views—that is, you cannot
>   create a visual interface based solely on layer objects. Layers
>   provide infrastructure for your views. Specifically, layers make it
>   easier and more efficient to draw and animate the contents of views
>   and maintain high frame rates while doing so. However, there are many
>   things that layers do not do. Layers do not handle events, draw
>   content, participate in the responder chain, or do many other things.
>   For this reason, every app must still have one or more views to handle
>   those kinds of interactions.
>
> In iOS, every view is backed by a corresponding layer object but in OS
>   X you must decide which views should have layers. In OS X v10.8 and
>   later, it probably makes sense to add layers to all of your views.
>   However, you are not required to do so and can still disable layers in
>   cases where the overhead is unwarranted and unneeded. Layers do
>   increase your app’s memory overhead somewhat but their benefits often
>   outweigh the disadvantage, so it is always best to test the
>   performance of your app before disabling layer support.
>
> When you enable layer support for a view, you create what is referred
>   to as a layer-backed view. In a layer-backed view, the system is
>   responsible for creating the underlying layer object and for keeping
>   that layer in sync with the view. All iOS views are layer-backed and
>   most views in OS X are as well. However, in OS X, you can also create
>   a layer-hosting view, which is a view where you supply the layer
>   object yourself. For a layer-hosting view, AppKit takes a hands off
>   approach with managing the layer and does not modify it in response to
>   view changes.

Read : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW3

**Now time for Some QNA**

*Question 1:*

> My understanding is that UIView (as part of UIKit) uses a normal
>   CALayer under the hood to draw its content. If this is correct, then
>   CAShapeLayer (or CALayer in general) would be the exact same thing,
>   only without the extras UIKit gives you

Again Quoting Apple doc

> Layer-backed views create an instance of the CALayer class by default,
>   and in most cases you might not need a different type of layer object.
>   However, Core Animation provides different layer classes, each of
>   which provides specialized capabilities that you might find useful.
>   Choosing a different layer class might enable you to improve
>   performance or support a specific type of content in a simple way

Clearly when you try to draw various shapes using `CAShapeLayer` is beneficial in terms of performance when compared to `CALayer`.

*Question 2*

> Is CAShapeLayer faster? Is UIKit more optimised for gesture
>   recognition or user interaction in general?

Clearly Layers do not handle events, draw content, participate in the responder chain, or do many other things. So none of the layer can recognize user interactions no matter whether its CALayer or CAShapeLayer

*Question 3*

> At this point, I'm not sure whether to use UIViews or CAShapeLayers

As you have specified in your question you want user interactions of red circles and because we are now aware of the fact that CAShapeLayer/CALayer will not respond to user interaction its pretty clear that you have to use UIView rather than layer.

Comment: Yes, I read that. "(...)For this reason, every app must still have one or more views to handle those kinds of interactions(...)". If they mean, the layers should generally be embedded in a `UIView`, it would mean `CAShapeLayers` would be the best in my case (as the embedding `UIView` can handle interactions). If they mean, every layer needs its own view (= use a `UIView` that's backed by a layer), I should use `UIView`s. I'm not sure about this. I mean, I do have a `UIView` in which I do all of this, I just don't know if I should use `subviews` or `sublayers`

Comment: @quantm : Every single View in iOS is layer backed. By default your Views comes with a CALayer and you cant replace the existing CALayer whatever the layer you add will be the sublayer to that, SO you can use CAShapeLayer and add it as sublayer to your view's layer. You cant use simply layer without view because you want the user to interact with the circles

Comment: If its a simple animation without user interactions then you could have used CALayers and add them to viewController's view and apply various CoreAnimation API to animate it but because you need tap on every circle you need to create view for every individual circle and for each view you can add CAShapeLayer as sublayer and then add the circle view as subView to ViewController View

Comment: Rather create view's for each circle and use corner radius property to make it circular add it as subview to your ViewController's view. Animating individual views would be costly as all the animations are dealt by CPU and Core animation (which uses Layer ) makes use of GPU there by reducing load on CPU. Make sure you use CADisplayLink to refresh the position of view in sync with screen refresh rate and also if possible use Sprite kit and create node for each circle and let metal take care of animation :) Few possible options

Comment: Sounds reasonable. What I thought was this: I subclass `UIView` and create a `MyRedCirclesView` view. Inside of this class, I add the circles as `sublayers` using `CAShapeLayer`. Then I would use the `touchesBegan(_:with:)` method of `MyRedCirclesView` to check if the touch is inside of one of the circle sublayers. Doesn't this work? And wouldn't this be faster, as the CPU just has to manage one single touch responder (from `MyRedCirclesView`), instead of many (if I use a `UIView` for every single circle).

Comment: @quantm : Sounds very much logical and should work fine :) Though its not the layer taking the touch its the view hosting the layer taking the touch :) All that you are doing is finding the touch point inside which layer :) Smart work around !!!!

Comment: By your approach u won't be able to draw IBActions from view (or declare selector on touchup inside event on views) but it will be your responsibility to trigger selector based on touch location

Comment: Okay, I think I will just open up a playground and try out different ways of implementing this. Thanks for your time, I learned a lot! :)

Comment: @quantm : Additional piece of advice :P you don't need touchesBegan to find touchLocation you can always use hitTest on UIView. you can always play around hitTest to do lot more things not just to figure out where user tapped but to decide which subview in the hierarchy should next get touch and all other things :) Quite interesting API :) Happy coding have fun :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting and appreciating the answer :)

Comment: Interesting! But hitTest would only work when using the subview approach, instead of the sublayer approach, right? Because it's only searching for subviews.

Comment: @quantm : Yeah in case of sublayers no matter what you use its always ur responsibility to trigger the selector as you cant handover touch events to layers :) I was just letting u know just another way to find touch location without using touchesBegan and also hitTest in itself can be used in various other scenarios like blocking touch on certain other subviews or trigger touch event on some other subview while user taps on completely different view n all was just iterating over possibilities not exactly for this problem but was just trying to tell u its potential :) sorry for confusing